# Getting variable in WMI filter to work?

Tags: powershell, escaping, wmi

Here is my WMI query which works:

```
$Query = "SELECT * from MSVM_ComputerSystem where ElementName='$Gen2'"
$VMs = gwmi -Query $Query -Namespace "root\virtualization\v2"
```

But I want to have a variable instead of a virtual machine name Gen2. Something like

```
$Query = "SELECT * from MSVM_ComputerSystem where ElementName='$VMName'"
$VMs = gwmi -Query $Query -Namespace "root\virtualization\v2"
```

Command `Get-Help about_Quoting_Rules` didn't help or I was unable to interpret the rules correctly. I've tried dozens of unsuccessful variations, trying to get it right.

Comment: If working with something like `$Gen2 = "Fences"; $Query = "SELECT * from Win32_Product where Name='$Gen2'"` It does work. Issue might not be with the query itself. Are you sure `$vmname` has a value? As a basic wmi query what I see that should have worked. Variables will expand in double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Queries with variables should work just fine, provided the nested variable is already defined when you define the query. Something like this:

```psh
$VMName = 'Gen2'
$Query  = "SELECT * FROM MSVM_ComputerSystem WHERE ElementName='$VMName'"

$VMs = gwmi -Query $Query -Namespace 'root\virtualization\v2'
```

It won't work if you define `$Query` first and `$VMName` afterwards

```psh
$Query  = "SELECT * FROM MSVM_ComputerSystem WHERE ElementName='$VMName'"
$VMName = 'Gen2'
```

because the nested variable is automatically expanded to an empty string, since it's not yet defined, so the value of `$Query` becomes `SELECT * FROM MSVM_ComputerSystem WHERE ElementName=''`.

If for some reason you must define the query first (e.g. as a template of sorts), and the variable at a later point in time (from user input or whatever), you must do something like this:

```psh
$Query  = "SELECT * FROM MSVM_ComputerSystem WHERE ElementName='{0}'"
$VMName = 'Gen2'

$VMs = gwmi -Query ($Query -f $VMName) -Namespace 'root\virtualization\v2'
```

or like this:

```psh
$Query  = "SELECT * FROM MSVM_ComputerSystem WHERE ElementName='`$VMName'"
$VMName = 'Gen2'

$VMs = gwmi -Query ($ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($Query)) `
       -Namespace 'root\virtualization\v2'
```

The first example defines `$Query` as a format string with a placeholder (`{0}`) and uses the format operator (`-f`) to fill in the actual value, while the second example expands an escaped variable (`` `$VMName ``).

You could also do a variant of the second example by "switching" the quotes, so you don't need to escape the `$`:

```psh
$Query  = 'SELECT * FROM MSVM_ComputerSystem WHERE ElementName="$VMName"'
$VMName = 'Gen2'

$VMs = gwmi -Query ($ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($Query)) `
       -Namespace 'root\virtualization\v2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
"ElementName=`"$Gen2`""
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I found the answer by myself thanks to command Get-Help about_Quoting_Rules after all. The trick is to use so called Here String. I'm posting it here for future reference.

I had to redesign the code slightly. This is the code that works. Just make sure to properly align Here String $filter and to use CRLF at the end of all lines of Here string. Perhaps there are many other solutions as well.

```
$filter=@"
ElementName='$VMName'
"@
$VMs = gwmi -class "MSVM_ComputerSystem" `
            -namespace "root\virtualization\v2" `
            -computername "." `
            -filter $filter
```

Complete Code is here:

```
Function WaitForVMShutDown($VMName){   
$filter=@"
ElementName='$VMName'
"@

$job = Start-Job { 
$state=""
    while ($state -ne "Stopped")
    {
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1

    $VMs = gwmi -class "MSVM_ComputerSystem" `
                -namespace "root\virtualization\v2" `
                -computername "." `
                -filter $filter  
        foreach ($VM IN $VMs)
        {
            switch ($VM.EnabledState)
            {
            2{$state="Running"}
            3{$state="Stopped"}
            32768{$state="Paused"}
            32769{$state="Suspended"}
            32770 {$state="Starting"}
            32771{$state="Taking Snapshot"}
            32773{$state="Saving"}
            32774{$state="Stopping"}
            }
        } 
    }
}
Wait-Job $job
}
WaitForVMShutDown("LondonDC")
```

Comment: Interresting. In this solution, you're running the wmi-query in a different way by using `-Filter` (which only is a parameter-version of "WHERE" in a query). Here-strings should have no impact what so ever. Are you saying that `$filter = "ElementName='$VMName'"` doesn't work with you new solution? To be honest with you, none of the changes you've made makes any difference compared to sample 2 in your question. Are you sure you actually tried sample 2 in your question (with `$vmname` defined first)? Your first sample is broken since the vmname is `Gen2` and you wrote `$Gen2`.

Comment: I've seen your answer after I posted my own solution. I've tried $filter = "ElementName='$VMName'", it also works, thanks. Your solution is more elegant.